# Exclude file pattern during svn checkout

Tags: svn

I have a repository with many binary files that aren't really needed for development. I am aware of the shallow checkouts and depth settings but this doesn't seem to work with file patterns.

I want to be able to do something like:

```
svn checkout http://repo/project --ignore "*.pdf; *.doc; *.png"
```

The files are placed across the project so its not possible to exclude any single folder or several of them to be able to use `depth` option.

The main point is not to download all those binary files since that takes a lot of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Subversion doesn't currently give you a way to do this.  You can ignore entire subdirectories, but not specific files based on a wildcard.

If there's enough of these binary files that it takes an onerous amount of time to check them out, then I suggest re-evaluating whether they should even be in your source code repository to begin with (as opposed to having their own repository).